# GLSL Shader is not compiling

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am working on a game and I am currently writing a shader to reflect light from an object and I keep getting the error message:

> ERROR: 0:25: '-' does not operate on 'vec3' and 'vec4'

fragmentShader file:

```
vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector); 

vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
```

vertexShader file:

```
toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition;
```

Version:

```
#version 400 core
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the complete shader files? You probably try to subtract a vec4 from a vec3 (or vice versa), somewhere.

Comment: fragmentShader: http://pastebin.com/YQZdTDWU
vertexShader: http://pastebin.com/CSqs02wS

Comment: You should add the code to the question. Otherwise the question/answers does not make sense anymore when the pastebin is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz
```

Returns a vec3 (x, y, z) - and you try to substract `worldPosition`, which is of type vec4.

You could change it to:

```
toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
```

Comment: Okay, I have done that and I now I am getting the following error:`ERROR: 0:34: Too many arguments to constructor of 'vec4'`

Comment: and the error occurs in `fragmentShader` at the line where it says `out_Colour = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords) + vec4(finalSpecular, 1,0);`

Comment: Yes, because in vec4(finalSpecular, 1, 0) you pass 5 arguments (A vec3 and 2 scalars).

Comment: Never realised I put 5 arguments, that was meant to be a decimal point

Comment: Okay so that compiles but it runs at just about 2fps on average

Comment: If this solved your issue please consider marking it as such. If your program runs slow - that is a whole different issue and can have numerous causes far beyond the scope of your shaders. It probably has nothing to do with the shaders.

Comment: It was running smoothly before I implemented the change

Comment: I found out what the issue was - it was because of the lack of GPU in my Macbook, I am now on my computer with a GPU and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition;
```

`worldPosition` is a vec4, `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz` is a vec3. It is not allowed to subtract a vec4 from a vec3.